# Schdeuling jobs after calling .start() APscheduler

Tags: python, scheduler, apscheduler

I am writing a program to schedule and cancel alarms in Flask. I am using the apscheduler library for the timings.

I need to be able to add events to the job queue at any point, so I need to be able to add events after the scheduler is run.

Currently, I have:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def cancel():
    job = events[0]
    job.remove()


def schedule():
    sched = scheds[0]
    try:
        sched.shutdown()
    except:
        pass
    job = sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date=t, args=['text'])
    events.append(job)
    sched.start()


def schedule2():
    sched = scheds[0]
    try:
        sched.shutdown()
    except:
        pass
    job = sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date=t2, args=['text'])
    events.append(job)
    sched.start()
```

Where scheds is an array to store a global scheduler, and events is an array which stores the events that are scheduled.

I need to run schedule, then schedule2, to schedule two different jobs. When I try this, I get an error which says that I cannot run schedule2 because the 'scheduler is already running'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to start the scheduler multiple times in the first place? You only need to start it once at the start of your application.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm because when I add a new job I need to restart the shceduler otherwise the event won't occur?

Comment: That is not how the scheduler works. Nowhere in the documentation does it say that you have to restart the scheduler after you add a job.